# How to maintain global error list?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

What is the best way to maintain global error list in PowerShell across multiple functions in different powershell files?

Currently I have

```
test1.ps1
func1(){..}
func2(){..}

test2.ps1
func3(){..}
func4(){..}
```

I need to get all the exception from all func1-func4,
So that i can generate a summarized error report out of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "across multiple files"?

Comment: I have created couple files based on the functionality, and each file has n number of functions. need to update the list if anything fails in any file.

Comment: How are you running/using the files?

Comment: Referring them in one file, like $CommonFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($Global:RootDirectory, "Common.ps1")
. ($CommonFile)

Comment: We're not playing 10 Questions here. Would you please edit your question so that it actually gives us an idea of both what you have and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Error` global variable already does that for you. It is an array of all the errors in a session. You can run something like below code to get all the error records in it.

```
foreach($ErrorEntry in $Error)
{
    #Do something here with $ErrorEntry
}
```

Also, you can implement custom solution like creating a single text file for a session and writing all the errors to that file.

Comment: Thanks. Looking for the same. Also added the custom error list.